# Reducing complexity of method

Tags: php, optimization, api, complexity

I'm trying to reduce the complexity of some methods, and I'm not exactly sure what approach to take. I'm currently building a PHP wrapper for a REST API, and the main problematic class is here:

https://github.com/petrepatrasc/blizzard-starcraft-api/blob/master/Service/ApiService.php

In short, since data retrieved from the API is not always consistent, I have to do this:

```
$portrait = new Portrait();
$portrait->setXCoordinate(isset($apiData['portrait']['x']) ? $apiData['portrait']['x'] : null)
    ->setYCoordinate(isset($apiData['portrait']['y']) ? $apiData['portrait']['y'] : null)
    ->setWidth(isset($apiData['portrait']['w']) ? $apiData['portrait']['w'] : null)
    ->setHeight(isset($apiData['portrait']['h']) ? $apiData['portrait']['h'] : null)
    ->setOffset(isset($apiData['portrait']['offset']) ? $apiData['portrait']['offset'] : null)
    ->setUrl(isset($apiData['portrait']['url']) ? $apiData['portrait']['url'] : null);
return $portrait;
```

What would be a better way of handling the problem, so that the method complexity goes down? I suppose that I can try and catch an "undefined index exception", but I kind of wanted to see if there's something a bit more elegant that I can use.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could remove some duplication with a `getPortraitValue` function:

```
function getPortraitValue($apiData, $key) {
    $portrait = $apiData['portrait'];
    if (isset($portrait[$key])) {
        return $portrait[$key];
    }
    return null;
}

$portrait = new Portrait();
$portrait->setXCoordinate(getPortraitValue($apiData, 'x')
    ->setYCoordinate(getPortraitValue($apiData, 'y'))
    ->setWidth(getPortraitValue($apiData, 'w'))
    ->setHeight(getPortraitValue($apiData, 'h'))
    ->setOffset(getPortraitValue($apiData, 'offset')
    ->setUrl(getPortraitValue($apiData, 'url');
return $portrait;
```

Comment: Yep, was thinking the same thing at one point, but this solution is essentially just a wrapper for the inline if. I say this because it is in fact a tad incorrect - if $apiData['portrait'][$key] does not exist, you'll still get a "Undefined index" exception, so instead you have to do: if (isset($apiData['portrait'][$key])) return $apiData['portrait'][$key];

Comment: @PetrePătraşc: Thank you, I've fixed that.

Comment: I'll try running some code analysis on that and checking if the lack of ternary does bring it down.

Comment: Yep, you were right! Method has been improved! https://scrutinizer-ci.com/g/petrepatrasc/blizzard-starcraft-api/inspections/5855cf86-6839-4e4a-a1c2-3123e6acff72

Accepting your answer, as it is the right solution.

Comment: @PetrePătraşc: Good to hear that, thanks :)